# why is json url showing different results in different browsers?

Tags: android, json

Following is my json url:

```
http://aerotagejobs.com/system/miscellaneous/api?params[user_sid]=12769&params[listing_type]=Job&params[listing_sid]=266626&function=save_listing&lang=en
```

in mozilla and chrome its showing:

```
{"result":"success","function_result":"success"}
```

but in explorer its showing :

```
{"result":"success","function_result":"denied"}
```

I am parsing this url in android and getting same output as explorer showing,but  I want to get output success instead of denied.Please help to find out what to do? thanks in advance.

Comment: I get "denied" in Chrome. Really, you're going to have to ask the people at aerotagejobs.com and/or study whatever API documentation they provide.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder :  So ,its not a browser problem?

Comment: @prem I too get "denied" so probably its your API key or something in the likes.

Comment: @prem I was a bit unclear, what i mean is that you're probably trying to access the wrong API or trying to access the wrong things provided by the API.